# Why does this MySQL query spill over to the next line

Tags: mysql, sql-update, syntax-error, sql-injection

The input would come in from a web form, and I am attempting an SQL injection via the form. In the password field, I attempt to put a single quote just to see what sort of error is invoked at the back end. I run this same query manually at the back end -

```
mysql> UPDATE users SET password = ''' WHERE username='admin';
```

I understand that there is a mismatch in the single quotes, but  I just want to see how the query behaves at the back end.

The query however doesn't run immediately. It spills over to the next line, as if it is waiting for more input.

`mysql> UPDATE users SET password = ''' WHERE username='admin';
    '> ';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin';
'' at line 1`

Why does it spill onto the second line? Why can't it just say something close to "syntax error near password"

Comment: It is waiting for more input. you have 5 single quotes in total - so mysql thinks you're in the middle of a string. if you executed this query from a non-interactive client, you _would_ get the syntax error

Comment: As above, the console thinks the string hasn't closed yet, nor the client ended the statement with a semicolon.

Comment: @ pala_ I'll accept this as the answer if you wish to change this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows writing a [literal `'` within a string literal quoted with `'`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html#idm140543869648144) by two consecutive `''`:

> There are several ways to include quote characters within a string:
>
> - A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`'`” may be written as “`''`”.
>
> […]

So the `''` immediately after the opening `'` is interpreted as a single literal `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an escape character as:  `\'`

```
mysql> UPDATE users SET password = '\'' WHERE username='admin';
```

Comment: That sort of defeats the purpose of trying 'sql injection'